# Trying to display a values from multiple API fetch

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, axios

Currently I'm reading some stock/share names from my DB (Mongo) and trying to display their price by calling an API for each one of them on my component, but I'm getting only the last one.

HTML

```
<div class="posts-container">
        <div class="post" v-for="post in posts" 
        v-bind:key="post['2. Symbol'] " >
        <p class="text">{{ post['2. Symbol'] }}  </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

JS

```
data(){
    return {
      posts: [],
      error: '',
      text: ''
    }
  }, 
async created() {

    try {
      const acoes = await APIService.getPosts();
        acoes.map(data => {
          fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=${data.name}.SA&interval=15min&outputsize=compact`)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {

            this.posts = { ...this.posts, ...data} 

          });
        })
        console.log(this.posts);
    } catch (err) {
      this.error = err.message;
    }

  },
```

So as I have multiple values on my const acoes I expected to generate data for each one of them, but what I got is just for the last object.

What am I missing here? 
There's a smarter way of doing this instead of calling the API on the component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all` to combine all your result.

```
   const allFetches = acoes.map(
           data => fetch(...)
                      .then(response => response.json()
   )

   Promise.all(allFetches)
          .flatMap(result => result)
          .then(posts => {
              this.posts = posts;
          });
```